# Using cross-correlation to detect the beginning of a signal

Tags: audio, signal-processing, convolution, cross-correlation

I am using cross-correlation to find where an audio signal occurs within a recording. When doing this, the point of highest correlation is always found somewhere within the signal in the recording, but I'm looking for a way to find the point where that signal BEGINS in the recording. Does anybody know of a way to go about doing this, or if cross-correlation will even do the job? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if asking for an algorithm is appropriate on StackOverflow, because there are a lot of factors to selecting an algorithm (for example, how noisy is your environment?  how accurately do you need to detect the start, does the signal have any unique characteristics, how long are the vectors, are there CPU performance concerns etc etc) so it typically falls under "Closed by moderator for being too open ended"  thing.  You might try the dsp stack exchange site or quora?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268519/how-can-i-ask-for-an-algorithm-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Ask on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If your signal is stationary, then instead of looking for a maxima using a single cross-correlation window, try looking for a maximum difference between 2 adjacent signal-sized cross correlation windows.  If the prior window shows a very low correlation, and the current window shows a very high correlation, then the likelihood that you are right at a transition edge is good.

Comment: That is a really smart idea, I'm going to try it. Thanks!